# Kotlin: Equivalent of property wrappers from Swift

Tags: java, swift, kotlin

What is the equivalent property wrappers for Kotlin:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Foo {

    var wrappedValue: String {
        get {
            return "Test
        }
    }

}
```

`@Foo var test: String`

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this question suggests that you're trying to port a Swift app to Kotlin by switching out Swift terms for Kotlin terms. If that's the case, you'll have a really rough time. You'll end up with awful psuedo-Swift Kotlin code, which is neither like its Swift counterpart (anymore), nor is it good Kotlin code that any other kotlin dev would recognize or want to work with.

Comment: I haven't learned Swift yet, but from a quick glance at a tutorial about Swift property wrappers, it looks to me like they are very similar to Kotlin [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html). But also, some of the simpler functionality of property wrappers can be done in Kotlin directly with custom getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin's property getters/setters are not sufficient to implement a property wrapper (which adds a layer of separation between code that manages how a property is stored and the code that defines a property according to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html). Delegated properties are the mechanism to achieve the same in Kotlin.

For the read-only example in the question, property wrappers don't really make sense, in Kotlin you would simply write (no need for delegates):

```
val test = "Test"
```

The example from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html is better suited to show the "equivalent" in Kotlin.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct TwelveOrLess {
    private var number = 0
    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { return number }
        set { number = min(newValue, 12) }
    }
}

@TwelveOrLess var height: Int
```

Above could be implemented like this in Kotlin:

```
var twelveOrLess: Int = 0
    set(value) {
        field = value.coerceAtMost(12)
    }

var height by ::twelveOrLess
```

For more complex examples you could use a class to delegate to:

```
class TwelveOrLess(private val initValue: Int = 0) {
    private var number = initValue
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>)=  number
    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        number = value.coerceAtMost(12)
    }
}

var height by TwelveOrLess()
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, there are several options from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) for how to add custom behavior to properties. There are basically two options: custom setters / getters, and [Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Some things that may be different in Kotlin:

- Properties are `val` or `var`. `val` is like `final` in Java, can only be assigned once, `var` can be reassigned.
- Both kinds can have custom getters. `var`s can have custom setters.
- If you want a backing field, Kotlin provides one for you. Just use the keyword `field` in a setter or getter.
- Kotlin properties do not have an implicit default value. You must initialize in the constructor (or via an `init` block) or at the declaration after an `=`.
- Some properties are actually computed and don't actually store anything. In this case, there is no backing `field`, and no initializer is required (or allowed).

Example:

```
class Dog {
    // Must have initial value, default getter and setter. Value can come from constructor.
    val isNice: Boolean = true 
        set(value) { ... } // This produces an error, no setters on vals

    // Must have initial value, default getter
    var age: Int = 0 
        set(value) { if (value >= 0) field = value }

    // Value is just computed, has no field and cannot have initial value
    var ageInDogYears: Int 
        get() = age * 7
        set(value) { age = value / 7 }
}
```